# lodash sortBy doesn't work with seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

Maybe I need to convert the array into real date to make it work? if use moment will the performances an issue because I need to sort the array as well.

```js
const arr = [{
  "created_at": "2017-07-19 10:37:20"
}, {
  "created_at": "2017-07-19 10:38:02"
}, {
  "created_at": "2017-07-19 10:38:06"
}, {
  "created_at": "2017-07-19 10:38:35"
}, {
  "created_at": "2017-07-19 10:39:21"
}, {
  "created_at": "2017-07-19 10:39:49"
}, {
  "created_at": "2017-07-19 10:42:06"
}, {
  "created_at": "2017-07-19 10:42:20"
}, {
  "created_at": "2017-07-19 10:45:01"
}, {
  "created_at": "2017-07-19 10:45:09"
}]
console.log(_.sortBy(arr, 'created_at'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.2.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I tried the code and it works. I even modified the ordering of the items, because **the ones you posted are already sorted**.

Answer (score 2):

Lodash sortBy is working as expected with your data but you have already posted sorted data that is why you are receiving the same result.